# Encoding newlines with JAXB

Tags: java, xml, encoding, jaxb

I have some java objects that get marshalled by JAXB into xml, one of the fields contains new lines.

I've looked at the hex values of the string in this field, and where I have a new line it's 0D0A which is CRLF or \r\n. Fine. But when it goes through the JAXB marhsalling, the resulting string contains \r\n.

So

```
line 1 \r\n line 2
```

becomes

```
line 1 &#13;\r\n line2
```

which is causing some problems in the system that receives the xml. Any ideas why this would happen and how I could fix it? If I strip out all \r characters before it gets to jaxb, then I get the expect \r\n which is fine.

Running on tomcat 6, Java 6, tested under Windows 8 and Solaris.

Thanks.

Comment: are you sure about that second version?  do you actually mean `&#13;\n`?

Comment: Yes, I mean what it says - each new line becomes &#13;\r\n. I know it's weird but that's the problem!